# Combine nested facets with ggtext

Tags: r

I want to combine nested facets (ggh4x) with italics (ggtext), but my example code does not work. What have I done wrong?

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggbeeswarm)
library(ggh4x)
library(ggtext)

df <- transform(iris, Nester = ifelse(Species == "setosa", "Short Leaves", "Long Leaves")) %>%
  as_tibble() %>%
  mutate(Nester = factor(Nester),
         Species_it = case_when(Species == "setosa" ~ "*setosa*",
                                Species == "versicolor" ~ "*versicolor*",
                                Species == "virginica" ~ "*virginica*"),
         Species_it = factor(Species_it))

df %>%
  pivot_longer(!c(Species, Species_it, Nester), names_to = "Measure", values_to = "Value") %>%
  ggplot(aes(Measure, Value)) +
  geom_beeswarm() +
  theme(strip.text = element_markdown()) +
  facet_nested(~ Nester + Species_it)
```

When I use `face = "italic"` in `element_markdown` all facet header are *italic*, including "Nester". That's why I tried to do it with `ggtext`.

[image]

Comment: I just ran your code, and it works for me. Nesters are in italics: https://i.imgur.com/5QHvoea.png -- Update your packages and try again. It is not reproducible for me.

Comment: Ok, I already updated my packages before I ran the code. Maybe I have to reinstall them. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Make sure you close out of R and open a fresh instance since there is a chance that another package has a conflict which causes this issue. Good luck.

Comment: When I go back from R4.2.1 to R4.1.3 it is working.